# Checkbox item value show on textbox c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box named cmbbx_size. I need to display the item that the user will select on  textbox1 when the btnShow is selected and at the same time show the selected item's price on textbox2. For example.

The user selected the item "Large", the item will show on the textbox1 and the price of it which is 45 will show on textbox2. Both of these will only show when the btnShow is clicked.

I already knew how to display the item selected on textbox1 but I cannot display the corresponding price on textbox2.

Comment: If it's an assignment, state this explicitly because you probably have limited tools to use (so you should say *I can only use this and that* and you should also show what you have done so far). -- This kind of *distributed selection* is usually performed using databindings that automate the whole procedure, no matter how large or small the application is. -- BTW, in the question's title, you ask about a CheckBox, but in the body you're referring to a ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this ,

In `cmbbx_size` 3 items `Small,Medium and Large`.

Choose an item and when `btnShow.Click` the item and price in TextBox1 and TextBox2

```
private void cmbbx_size_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "";
    TextBox2.Text = "";
}

private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbbx_size.Text == "Small")
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "Small";
        TextBox2.Text = "25";
    }
    if (cmbbx_size.Text == "Medium")
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "Medium";
        TextBox2.Text = "30";
    }
    if (cmbbx_size.Text == "Large")
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "Large";
        TextBox2.Text = "45";
    }
}
```